# Расстановка знаков препинания в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, как

Необходимо уточнить, как правильно оформить предложение:

> Я как истинный цветок всегда весною
> расцветаю.

Должно ли быть тире перед *как* или запятая? Нужно ли двоеточие перед *всегда* или запятая?

Comment: @Maria, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Нужны запятые. В вашем примере сравнительный оборот  содержит в себе оттенок причинного значения: *Я, как истинный цветок, всегда весною расцветаю.* - "будучи истинным цветком".